# How to speed up flutter clean when having 20 flavors?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Our app have many flavors (around 20).

When running flutter clean, flutter run internally the following command for each flavors which took some times :

```
/usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/my_user/Documents/projects/flutter-app/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme client_one clean
...
/usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/my_user/Documents/projects/flutter-app/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme client_two clean
```

Flutter clean can took more than 10min.

Do you have any idea ?

My device :

MacBook Pro M1

Flutter 3.0.5 / 3.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script instead of flutter clean on my laptop and my CI. It work well but yep, need to maintain it along flutter upgrade to not forgot something...

```bash
# Reproduced the steps from flutter_sdk/package/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/clean.dart picked from flutter 3.7.12.
# Use this if you can't use the `flutter clean` command because of the slowness of the tool if you have for example 100 or more schemes.
# Each individual xcodebuild clean can took 30s so it's too long...

if [ -f "pubspec.yaml" ]; then
    echo "Starting..."
else
    echo "You are not at the root of a flutter project !"
    exit 1
fi

rm -rf build \
  .dart_tool \
  .packages \
  android/.android \
  ios/Flutter/ephemeral \
  ios/.ios \
  ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig \
  ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh \
  ios/Flutter/App.framework \
  ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework \
  ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec \
  .flutter-plugins-dependencies \
  .flutter-plugins \
  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/* \
  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products/* \
  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

echo "Done !"
```